# Android app crashing on Firebase UI Facebook sign in

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, user-interface, authentication

I have an application that uses `FirebaseAuthUI`, it enables Facebook sign in, everything works fine in Debug, but when I upload the application in release mode, the application crashes with this log:

```
Facebook provider cannot be configured without dependency. Did you forget to add 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:VERSION' dependency?
com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI$IdpConfig$FacebookBuilder.<init>
```

I have debuged the application, and the error is produced in this line:

```
if (!ProviderAvailability.IS_FACEBOOK_AVAILABLE) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(
                            "Facebook provider cannot be configured " +
                                    "without dependency. Did you forget to add " +
                                    "'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:VERSION' dependency?");
                }
```

This means that Facebook is not available, however I've setup the Facebook hash value with the release key store and key store path using this code:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <aliasName> -keystore <keystoreFilePath> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Which gave the hash that I've put into the Facebook app settings.
I'm using this library as a dependency in my `build.gradle` file : `'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.+'`.

**Extra info** The Facebook application is installed in my phone.

Comment: try adding the `Proguard` rule, i had similar problem with twitter sdk.. It is an issue mentioned at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113513217, Disabling the r8 worked for me

Comment: it didn't work :(

Comment: Disabling the r8? have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `ProviderAvailability` checks are performed using the `reflection API`. If you are using `Proguard`, add the below line in your `proguard-rules.pro` file to prevent class name obfuscation:

```
-keepnames class com.facebook.login.LoginManager
```